Unsatisfied dependencies for type AbstractDao with qualifiers @CustomQualifier in CDI
I'm working on a Spring project using CDI (Contexts and Dependency Injection) and I'm encountering an issue with dependency injection. The error message I'm getting is:
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type AbstractDao with qualifiers @CustomQualifier
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject @CustomQualifier private com.example.MyBean.dao
  at com.example.MyBean.dao(MyBean.java:0)

Here are the relevant parts of my code:
CustomQualifier.java
package com.example.annotations; 

import jakarta.inject.Qualifier; 
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType; 
import java.lang.annotation.Retention; 
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy; 
import java.lang.annotation.Target; 

@Qualifier 
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) 
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE}) 
public @interface CustomQualifier { 
    String value(); 
} 

AbstractDao.java
package com.example.dao; 

public abstract class AbstractDao { 
    // Abstract methods and common functionality 
} 

DaoImpl.java
package com.example.dao; 

import com.example.annotations.CustomQualifier; 
import jakarta.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped; 

@CustomQualifier("daoImpl") 
@ApplicationScoped 
public class DaoImpl extends AbstractDao { 
    // Implementation of abstract methods 
} 

MyBean.java
package com.example; 

import com.example.annotations.CustomQualifier; 
import com.example.dao.AbstractDao; 
import jakarta.enterprise.context.SessionScoped; 
import jakarta.inject.Inject; 
import jakarta.inject.Named; 
import java.io.Serializable; 

@Named 
@SessionScoped 
public class MyBean implements Serializable { 
    @Inject 
    @CustomQualifier("daoImpl") 
    private AbstractDao dao; 

    // Other methods and properties 
} 

beans.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<beans xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/beans_4_0.xsd" 
       version="4.0" bean-discovery-mode="annotated"> 
</beans> 

Dependencies
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId> 
    <artifactId>weld-servlet-shaded</artifactId> 
    <version>5.1.3.Final</version> 
</dependency> 
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId> 
    <artifactId>jakarta.faces</artifactId> 
    <version>4.0.8</version> 
</dependency> 

Environment:

Java 17
PrimeFaces 14
Tomcat 10.1.x
Spring 6

Issue:
The CDI container is unable to resolve the dependency for AbstractDao with the qualifier @CustomQualifier("daoImpl"). I have annotated the DaoImpl class with the same qualifier and scope, but the injection point in MyBean still fails.
What I've Tried:

Ensured that the DaoImpl class is annotated with @CustomQualifier("daoImpl") and @ApplicationScoped.
Verified that the injection point in MyBean is correctly annotated with @CustomQualifier("daoImpl").

Question:
What could be causing this unsatisfied dependency issue and how can I resolve it? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Did you try @AliasFor(annotation = Qualifier.class, attribute = "value") on String value();?

Please help me understand, in the given example what is the need to create a @CustomQualifier? Why can't we simply use @Qualifier, does this not work with @Qualifier too?

@BalusC No its not related to my previous question.

@BalusC No its not related to my previous question. Its a Spring based Project (build as WAR, earlier daoImpl is Spring managed bean. WELD is complaining when I try to ingest Spring Managed bean (daoImpl)  inside a CDI Managed Bean (MyBean ).  So I am converting Spring Managed bean to CDI Managed Bean. I am creating CustomQualifier since jakarta.inject.Qualifier doesnt support assigning a value so that I can differentiate multiple implementation of AbstractDao.

@SharadPaul -  I am creating CustomQualifier since jakarta.inject.Qualifier doesnt support assigning a value so that I can differentiate multiple implementation of AbstractDao.

@dan1st I am creating CustomQualifier based on  jakarta.inject.Qualifier not the Spring based one

Does @AliasFor not work with Jakarta Inject annotations in Spring (Boot) projects?
